# Does an elasticsearch parent entry have to exist before its children?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using parent relationships in elasticsearch, and I'm wondering if the parent must exist before the child. Elasticsearch doesn't complain when I add a child with an id of a not yet existing parent. However, it seams (I haven't completely validated it yet), that once the parent has been added, sometimes the "has_parent" query returns the entry and othertimes not.
I've searched for an answer but haven't found it. Anyone have a clue ?

Answer (score 4):

ElasticSearch isn't a relational DB : the parent, which id is used to insert documents of the children type,  doesn't have to exist.

However, once you add the parent document, you may experience problems as parent document and its children must live on the same shard.

To achieve this, ElasticSearch use the parent id as the routing key. If the parent ID is not specified, the request will probably be forwarded to the wrong shard [as specified in the documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/indexing-parent-child.html). This could explain the behavior you are talking about the "has_parent" query.

If you want to add the parent after the children, you have to delete and reindex it to be sure it is stored on the same shard as its parent.

Comment: I did specify a parent_id (and elasticsearch won't let me index without it anyway as the relationship is declared in my mapping). But there is no existing entry with the same value as id. Is the routing dependent on the existance of an entry or only the value of the key is used ? If its only the value then I should be ok, and my problem is somewhere else.

Comment: From the documentation I should be OK. But, now I see whats wrong. My parent also has its own parent an therefore gets routed there... so I should get the child to get routed to the same shard as its grand-parent, or remove this second parent-child relationship.

Comment: Imo, the routing value is enough. If you index the parent with the parent value you used for the child as id, it will be stored on the same shard.

Answer (score 2):

As I had understood it the relationship IS loosely coupled. So you CAN index a child before it's parent gets indexed but have to ensure the child gets indexed in the same shard as its future parent. This means if you have a simple parent-child relationship you have to know the parent's id value. BUT if the structure of you index is more complex, the routing might get complex also. If your parent, itself has a parent, then everything should be routed in the same place as the grandparent.

Comment: You can find more information about grandparents/grandchildren relations [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/grandparents.html#grandparents)

Comment: Thanks hadn't seen that one. Indeed interesting.